# Ajax GIF Loader not working in IE and Firefox (Latest) but working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

The GIF loader is working fine in Chrome(Latest version), but it never animates in IE and Firefox(Latest).

Here is the code:

```
 $("#DIALOG").dialog({
                  buttons : {
                    "Yes" : function() {
                        $("#loading_image").show();
                      window.location.href = targetUrl;
                    },
                    "No" : function() {
                              $(this).dialog("close");
                    }

                  }
                });
```

Calls this:

```
<div id="loading_image">
        <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
    </div>
```

Comment: I have fixed this..The problem was with window.location. Firefox freezes the GIF on location href. So You just need to use Iframe to use AJAX in firefox just before, window.location.href.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your ajax-loader extension.

I Think your image is in PNG format : ajax-loader.png

Comment: No it's in GIF. And it's animating fine in Google chrome. But not in firefox and IE

Comment: would you please just share me link of your loader ? @user3751832

Answer (score 0):

Just Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/y9Y4Y/) is working fine in firefox..

Please check :

1. your image extension..     `gif or png`
2. Source path or your image `src="images/ajax-loader.gif"`

Comment: No it's in GIF. And it's animating fine in Google chrome. But not in firefox and IE

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y9Y4Y/ Check this.. this code is working.. can u pls create a fiddle so we can help you better..